# Вставка записей в Entity FrameWork при многие ко многим

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Допустим, имеется Модель, которая была сгенерирована из БД.

В этой БД есть сущности `User`, `Book`, `UserBook` (Связывает 2 сущности между собой).

Соответственно - это 3 класса в Entity Framework.

Допустим, мне нужно одновременно создать 10 `Book` и тут же выдать их `User`, заполнив `UserBook`.

UserBook имеет следующие атрибуты: UserBook_Id,Book_id(FK),User_id(FK) и специфические поля=> EF сгенерировал это в отдельную сущность.

Как это можно красиво сделать?

Comment: я не совсем понял вопрос, где именно подвох? 
зачем заполнять UserBook? воспользуйтесь виртуальными св-вами и прикрепите Book-и напрямую к User. EF сам за вас создаст новые записи в UserBook

Comment: @nikita, если не ошибаюсь, то так можно сделать если бы UserBook имел только составной PK из FK к Book и FK к User, а у меня там собственный PK.(Дополнил вопрос)

Comment: а разве одна книга может быть у нескольких пользователей?

Answer (score 1):

```
        Model1 ctx = new Model1();

        var book = new Book()
        {
            ID = 1,
            Title = "qwe"               
        };

        User user = new User()
        {
            ID = 1,
            Title = "xzc"
        };

        ctx.Book.Add(book);
        ctx.User.Add(user);

        UserBook ub = new UserBook()
        {
            ID = 1,
            User = user,
            Book = book
        };

        ctx.UserBook.Add(ub);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.